# Stepping Up power (from 0.02-0.6 DC V input to 5-12 DC V output)

Tags: power-electronics, dc-dc-converter

I want do design DC-DC converter to have a power supply that can charge an electronic device.
The issue behind in that the expected input range is 0.04-0.6 V DC. I chose both [MT3608](https://www.olimex.com/Products/Breadboarding/BB-PWR-3608/resources/MT3608.pdf) and [LTC3108](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/LTC3108.pdf?ADICID=SYND_WW_P682800_PF-snapeda).

[image]

[image]

My questions are.

1. What are the factors (i.e., RLC components) that I need to change in order to achieve my objectives?
2. Are there any suggestions to simulate it properly so see the effect of it? I tried LTspice be there was some difficulties.
3. I had an issue behind the factors that are connected to these IC-chips, why these values are connected with them specifically.

Comment: Please show your schematic. Did you manage to start the LTC3108 from 60 mV?

Comment: `Stepping Up power (from 0.02-0.6 DC V input to 5-12 DC V output)` ..that should say `stepping up voltage` ... power does not increase

Comment: Make a synchronous boost circuit..It will need a few volts (e.g.) from a battery, to startup, after which it can harvest power from very low voltages

Comment: the MT3608, whatever that actually is, seems to be unnecessary and more of a problem than a solution. So, step 1: Ignore that part for now. Step 2: the Analog device LTC3108 comes with an extensive datasheet that allows you to design a step up converter as required, as long as your requirements are physically possible. You sadly don't specify requirements at all – how much current do you want to be able to get after stepping up? What's the current capacity / internal resistance of your microbial cells?

Comment: LTC3108 should do the job correctly if conected correctly. Go over my other answer and connect wiring EXACTLY as I and datasheet show. Use a jumper in breatboard between two GND pins for LTC3108. DO NOT cross other two jumpers as at present. Repoprt bac.k

Answer (score -2):

Your target input voltage is too low. You will not be able to achieve a boost converter with an input voltage below 0.7V, because about min. 0.7V is what industry leading boost converters can a achieve.

Comment: I agree. Just with the inherent impedance of the circuit, it may not yield any current/voltage at all. Thought theorically it "should" be possible. Doesn't mean you will.

Comment: LTC3108 operates down to 20 mV.

Comment: The actual issue is the my project is using MFCs (Microbial Fuel Cells) , which will be as 12 single chambers, and my job as electrical engineer is to stepping up in order to change any battery, such as Lithium ion battery. Any suggestions to achieve it ?

Comment: It's not a shopping question (because that would be OT)..So it's irrelevant what commercial booster can achieve. A synchronous boost can theoretically use arbitrarily low input voltages.